# Shopify REST API: send invoice with a specific locale

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

In shopify, when you buy from a translated storefront, you automatically get the invoice in the correct language.

I want to achieve the same thing with the Shopify REST APIs.
Unfortunately, the [API documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/draftorder#send_invoice-2020-07) doesn't show anything to set the locale.

**How can I specify a locale when sending an invoice with Shopify REST API?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of digging and no support feedback of any kind of Shopify devs, the answer at this date is now clear:

#### This is simply not possible

If you need this kind of feature you need to implement in your site email generations.